# How to run PyScripter from a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyscripter

How do you run PyScripter from a virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

**The [answer was buried in the FAQ comments](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ); re-posting here for others:**

There's a problem if you use PyScripter with the remote python engine in a virtualenv environment. On Microsoft Windows, if ENV is your virtual python environment (created with 'python virtualenv.py ENV'), then after switching to this environment, the python.exe executable is located in C:\Python27\ENV\Scripts. (Or whatever your Python version and installation directory is) However, PyScripter expects it to be in C:\Python27\ENV.

You can use this workaround: Create a symbolic link from C:\Python27\ENV\python.exe to C:\Python27\ENV\Scripts\python.exe . On Windows Vista or 7, you may use the mklink command to do this:

```
mklink C:\Python27\ENV\python.exe C:\Python27\ENV\Scripts\python.exe
```

(you'll need administrator privilleges to do this). Start PyScripter via a batch file with the following commands:

```
CALL C:\Python27\ENV\Scripts\activate.bat
SET PYTHONHOME=%VIRTUAL_ENV%
START project.psproj
```

- The first line activates the virtual environment ENV.
- The second line sets the PYTHONHOME environment variable to the one defined by virtualenv, i.e. 'C:\Python27\ENV'. This is that Python finds all libraries specific to that environment.
- The last line starts PyScripter via a project file. You might as well call PyScripter.exe directly.

*Versions tested: Python 2.7.3 PyScripter 2.5.3.0 x86 virtualenv 1.8.2 on Windows 7 (32 bit)*